# Error parsing JSON using jQuery 1.9 but no error in eval

Tags: java, json, jquery

I am overriding java.Object.toString() to get JSON without using any JSON library on the server side of my app.

jQuery version `1.9.0` and
JDK version `1.6.21`
As a response to:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(url:"/getAvailableAddress.do",
type:"GET",
data:"cat=PreOrder&task=getAvailableAddress"+$(form).serialize() )
    .done(function(response) { console.log(response); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

I am getting the following JSON from my server:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "alk": "123456",
            "qualifier": "golden",
            "buildingname": "Rose Appartments",
            "buildingnumber": "1245",
            "Street": "Nehru Street",
            "Town": "Kolkata",
            "Postcode": "MQK 456"
        },
        {
            "alk": "123457",
            "qualifier": "platinum",
            "buildingname": "Lily Appartments",
            "buildingnumber": "1585",
            "Street": "Modi Street",
            "Town": "Bangalore",
            "Postcode": "476 AKQ"
        }
    ]
}
```

when I try to do the following:

```
var result = $.parseJSON(response);
alert(result.response[0].alk);
```

I am getting a javascript error in Jquery file:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
st.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
(anonymous function)
```

But when I use the following, I am getting no errors at all.

```
var result = eval(response);
alert(result.response[0].alk);
```

What am I doing wrong with the jQuery Parse?

Comment: How are you getting the JSON?

Comment: Did you try `var result = JSON.parse(response);`, it's what jQuery should be using internally if your browser supports it ?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - I am using $.ajax() and logging the JSON to console.

Comment: If the console shows an object, that's what you have, no need to parse it again.

Comment: @adeneo - the console doesn't show an object, it's just text response.

Comment: Then you'll need to parse it, did you try copy pasting the text from the console into json lint and see if it's valid, and did you try JSON.parse to see what errors that gives.

Comment: @adeneo - I got the issue and resolved it. JSON.parse() needed stringification of the returned object which is an array of text characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery "intelligently guesses" the return of an AJAX request if the `dataType` property is not set. It parses it accordingly.

> ## jQuery.ajax()
>
> dataType (default: **Intelligent Guess** (xml, json, script, or html))

If you returned JSON as well as the proper headers, the data you will receive in the callback will be pre-parsed already according to its intended type. No need to parse anymore.

Also, check for the [proper syntax of JSON](http://json.org). You can use [JSON validators](http://jsonlint.com/) that are available online.

Answer (score 1):

If the response from the server includes the "var response =" then technically this isn't valid JSON. JSON is just the object notation {} and the values inside that object notation. There shouldn't be an = or a var in front of it. Eval() wouldn't catch this because the larger statement is valid JavaScript (it is creating a variable called response)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @adeneo. I got my issue resolved by researching your `JSON.parse()`.

The following code works:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(url:"/getAvailableAddress.do",
type:"GET",
data:"cat=PreOrder&task=getAvailableAddress&"+$(form).serialize() )
    .done(function(response) { 
           var result =$.parseJSON('"'+response+'"'); 
           alert(result.response[0].alk);
     })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```